# What is Python's interpreter printing something in "a ++ 1" and why?

Tags: python

Here's something strange I noticed about my Python interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 10 2014, 08:19:18) 
[GCC 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 1
>>> for i in range(3):
...   for j in range(3):
...     a ++ 1
... 
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
>>>
```

What's happening here? Why is Python printing anything?

Comment: On a side note, I suspect what you wanted was `a += 1` - Python doesn't have the `++` increment operator.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that was a mistake I was aware of. The only confusion stemmed from the unexpected print and is already answered ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python interactive interpreter prints *all* [expression statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements) results unless they produce `None`:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> for i in range(3):
...     a
... 
1
1
1
```

This isn't limited to expression statements at the top level, this happens for expressions in [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) like loops too. The only exception to this are expression statements inside functions and classes:

```
>>> def foo():
...     a
... 
>>> foo()
>>> 
>>> class Foo():
...     a
...
>>>
```

Your `a ++ 1` expression simply adds 1 to `a`, but never alters `a` itself; Python interprets it the same as `a + (+1)` or `a + 1`, so you'll always see `2` echoed.

Comment: "The only exception to this are functions" - doesn't it apply to functions as well? In your example, if `a` was a function, it would still print something wouldn't it?

Comment: @Trengot: no, I mean that if you put `a`, on a line by itself, in a function and called it, `a` would not be echoed.

Comment: ahh, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Trengot: Python distinguishes between *expressions* and *statements*. Functions are one kind of statement (a compound statement), `for` and `while` loops two other kinds.

Comment: @Trengot: so expressions, on their own on a line, will cause the Python interpreter to echo the result, unless that expression is part of a function. Note that class bodies (`class ....: ...`) are effectively executed as a function too, so no echoing takes place there either.

Answer (score 8):

`a ++ 1` is just doing a single addition. As jonrsharpe mentions in the comments, this value is printed in the loop because it returns a value other than `None`.

```
a = 1
a ++ 1 == a + (+1)  # True
a +- 1 == 0  # True
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I was more wondering why Python printed anything at all.

Comment: @d33tah because the interpreter outputs the result of the last expression (unless it's `None`) by default

Comment: Even in a loop? Ah, that's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually its `a+(+1)` the second `+` interpreted as the sign of `1` by python.

other examples:

```
>>> 3+-1
2
>>> 3++1
4
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I was more wondering why Python printed anything at all.

Comment: @d33tah  sorry what you mean by `anything`?

Comment: Actually, this was the first time I saw Python printing last expression in a loop and this made me wondering.

Comment: @Kasra the OP wasn't expecting to see any output during that operation

Comment: @d33tah ahan! the reason is what that Martijn says *Python interactive interpreter prints all expression results*